# is it possible to install python numba in python alpine image

Tags: python, alpine-linux

I am install python3 numba packages in GitHub actions, but the install process show error:

```
Collecting numba==0.56.4
  Downloading numba-0.56.4.tar.gz (2.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.4/2.4 MB 59.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [301 lines of output]
      /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
        warnings.warn(
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [258 lines of output]
            Running from numpy source directory.
            setup.py:86: DeprecationWarning:
      
              `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
              of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
              Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
              It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
              For more details, see:
                https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html
      
      
              import numpy.distutils.command.sdist
            Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
            Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
            Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
            Cythonizing sources
            INFO: blas_opt_info:
            INFO: blas_armpl_info:
            INFO: customize UnixCCompiler
            INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: blas_mkl_info:
            INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: blis_info:
            INFO:   libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: openblas_info:
            INFO:   libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: accelerate_info:
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
            INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
            INFO:   libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: atlas_3_10_blas_info:
            INFO:   libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: atlas_blas_threads_info:
            INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
            INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: atlas_blas_info:
            INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            /tmp/pip-wheel-eqyou62a/numpy_571e716b8f694316af15802515ca0b00/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:2077: UserWarning:
                Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
                Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
                A better performance should be easily gained by switching
                Blas library.
              if self._calc_info(blas):
            INFO: blas_info:
            INFO:   libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            /tmp/pip-wheel-eqyou62a/numpy_571e716b8f694316af15802515ca0b00/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:2077: UserWarning:
                Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
                Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
                numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
                the BLAS environment variable.
              if self._calc_info(blas):
            INFO: blas_src_info:
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            /tmp/pip-wheel-eqyou62a/numpy_571e716b8f694316af15802515ca0b00/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:2077: UserWarning:
                Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
                Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
                numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
                the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
              if self._calc_info(blas):
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
            INFO: lapack_opt_info:
            INFO: lapack_armpl_info:
            INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: lapack_mkl_info:
            INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: openblas_lapack_info:
            INFO:   libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: openblas_clapack_info:
            INFO:   libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: flame_info:
            INFO:   libraries flame not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: atlas_3_10_threads_info:
            INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
            INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
            INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
            INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: atlas_3_10_info:
            INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
            INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
            INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: atlas_threads_info:
            INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
            INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
            INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
            INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: atlas_info:
            INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
            INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
            INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: lapack_info:
            INFO:   libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            /tmp/pip-wheel-eqyou62a/numpy_571e716b8f694316af15802515ca0b00/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1902: UserWarning:
                Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
                Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
                numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
                the LAPACK environment variable.
              return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
            INFO: lapack_src_info:
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            /tmp/pip-wheel-eqyou62a/numpy_571e716b8f694316af15802515ca0b00/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1902: UserWarning:
                Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
                Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
                numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
                the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
              return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
            INFO:   FOUND:
            INFO:     language = c
            INFO:     define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]
            INFO:
            Warning: attempted relative import with no known parent package
            /tmp/pip-build-env-t_16bsry/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
              warnings.warn(msg)
            running bdist_wheel
            running build
            running config_cc
            INFO: unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
            running config_fc
            INFO: unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
            running build_src
            INFO: build_src
            INFO: building py_modules sources
            creating build
            creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10
            creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy
            creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/distutils
            INFO: building library "npymath" sources
            WARN: Could not locate executable armflang
            WARN: Could not locate executable gfortran
            WARN: Could not locate executable f95
            WARN: Could not locate executable ifort
            WARN: Could not locate executable ifc
            WARN: Could not locate executable lf95
            WARN: Could not locate executable pgfortran
            WARN: Could not locate executable nvfortran
            WARN: Could not locate executable f90
            WARN: Could not locate executable f77
            WARN: Could not locate executable fort
            WARN: Could not locate executable efort
            WARN: Could not locate executable efc
            WARN: Could not locate executable g77
            WARN: Could not locate executable g95
            WARN: Could not locate executable pathf95
            WARN: Could not locate executable nagfor
            WARN: Could not locate executable frt
            WARN: don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
      
      
            [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gcc'
      
      
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
                main()
              File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
                json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
              File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
                return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t_16bsry/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 230, in build_wheel
                return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t_16bsry/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
                self.run_setup()
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t_16bsry/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
                super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t_16bsry/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
                exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
              File "setup.py", line 494, in <module>
                setup_package()
              File "setup.py", line 486, in setup_package
                setup(**metadata)
              File "/tmp/pip-wheel-eqyou62a/numpy_571e716b8f694316af15802515ca0b00/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
                return old_setup(**new_attr)
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t_16bsry/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
                return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t_16bsry/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
                dist.run_commands()
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t_16bsry/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
                self.run_command(cmd)
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t_16bsry/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t_16bsry/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
                self.run_command('build')
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t_16bsry/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
                self.distribution.run_command(command)
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t_16bsry/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/tmp/pip-wheel-eqyou62a/numpy_571e716b8f694316af15802515ca0b00/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 62, in run
                old_build.run(self)
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t_16bsry/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
                self.run_command(cmd_name)
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t_16bsry/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
                self.distribution.run_command(command)
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t_16bsry/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/tmp/pip-wheel-eqyou62a/numpy_571e716b8f694316af15802515ca0b00/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 144, in run
                self.build_sources()
              File "/tmp/pip-wheel-eqyou62a/numpy_571e716b8f694316af15802515ca0b00/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 155, in build_sources
                self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
              File "/tmp/pip-wheel-eqyou62a/numpy_571e716b8f694316af15802515ca0b00/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 288, in build_library_sources
                sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
              File "/tmp/pip-wheel-eqyou62a/numpy_571e716b8f694316af15802515ca0b00/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
                source = func(extension, build_dir)
              File "/tmp/pip-wheel-eqyou62a/numpy_571e716b8f694316af15802515ca0b00/numpy/core/setup.py", line 758, in get_mathlib_info
                raise RuntimeError(
            RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program.
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
      ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 82, in fetch_build_egg
          subprocess.check_call(cmd)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmp2nz6gige', '--quiet', 'numpy<1.24,>=1.11']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      
      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-xchug7bl/numba_00413dce325d4a8a88447ef4c07c125f/setup.py", line 431, in <module>
          setup(**metadata)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 86, in setup
          _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 80, in _install_setup_requires
          dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 875, in fetch_build_eggs
          resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 789, in resolve
          dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1075, in best_match
          return self.obtain(req, installer)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1087, in obtain
          return installer(requirement)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 945, in fetch_build_egg
          return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 84, in fetch_build_egg
          raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
      distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmp2nz6gige', '--quiet', 'numpy<1.24,>=1.11']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

I think maybe install numba need gcc to compile the source code, and the alpine did not  have gcc by default. is it possible to install the dependencies in alpine? what should I do to make it work? should I install gcc in the base container? I still want to keep the image slim. This is my python dependencies:

```
fastapi==0.95.0
openai==0.27.0
sse-starlette==1.3.3
SQLAlchemy~=1.4.6
pydantic~=1.10.5
rembg==2.0.32
Pillow==9.5.0
aiohttp==3.8.4
aiosignal==1.3.1
anyio==3.6.2
async-timeout==4.0.2
asyncer==0.0.2
attrs==22.2.0
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==8.1.3
coloredlogs==15.0.1
filetype==1.2.0
flatbuffers==23.3.3
frozenlist==1.3.3
h11==0.14.0
httptools==0.5.0
humanfriendly==10.0
idna==3.4
ImageHash==4.3.1
imageio==2.27.0
lazy_loader==0.2
llvmlite==0.39.1
mpmath==1.3.0
multidict==6.0.4
networkx==3.1
numba==0.56.4
numpy==1.24.2
onnxruntime==1.14.1
opencv-python-headless==4.7.0.72
packaging==23.0
Pillow==9.5.0
platformdirs==3.2.0
pooch==1.7.0
protobuf==4.22.1
pydantic==1.10.7
PyMatting==1.1.8
python-dotenv==1.0.0
python-multipart==0.0.6
PyWavelets==1.4.1
PyYAML==6.0
rembg==2.0.32
requests==2.28.2
scikit-image==0.20.0
scipy==1.10.1
sniffio==1.3.0
starlette==0.26.1
sympy==1.11.1
tifffile==2023.3.21
tqdm==4.65.0
typing_extensions==4.5.0
urllib3==1.26.15
uvicorn==0.21.1
uvloop==0.17.0
watchdog==3.0.0
watchfiles==0.19.0
websockets==11.0
yarl==1.8.2
psycopg2-binary==2.9.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to create a separate container that includes all the  build tools you might need and then use it to compile the required packages:

```
FROM alpine:latest as builder
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev

FROM python:3.10-alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/
COPY --from=builder /usr/lib/gcc /usr/lib/gcc
RUN apk add --no-cache libstdc++
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

This creates two stages: in the first stage, it installs `gcc` and `musl-dev` and builds an intermediate image. In the second stage, it copies the necessary files from the intermediate image and installs `libstdc++` and the Python dependencies. This ensures that the final image remains slim and does not include any unnecessary build tools or dependencies.